# Best way to update values of Shapes in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, canvas, architecture

I have quite a big problem here. I am using MVVM in my drawing application (Caliburn.Micro) and I can't find a reasonable way to make it drawing the shapes with live preview.

The drawing canvas consists of a canvas which gets the input and feeds the data to the model and a Grid holding many canvases, one for each layer. The model fires events (I will use Line as example):

1. Event for creation of the Line - it creates a simple Line object with properties for start point, end point, color, thickness and a automatically generated ID. The event has the line and the layer it was added to.
2. On mouse move the end point of the line object created in 1. is updated and a new event is fired with the updated shape and its layer as a parameter.
3. On mouse up 2. happens too.

Now in the ViewModel which registers to these events I simply add to correct canvas an equivalent WPF shape (in this case System.Windows.Shapes.Line) and set the parameters when a shape is added. But I can't come with any idea which would be robust to update the shape parameters when the mouse is moved to show a live preview of the drawn shape.

I tried using dependency properties, but it didn't work and seemed to be an overkill (because of the number of shapes that will be in all these canvases). I also tried extending the Line, but it's not possible, because the class is sealed. I also need to interact with the shapes which are drawn (e.g. resizing, rotating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into the writeablebitmap and the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) extensions.  This will have pretty good performance, depending on how many things you have to render.  If you need to have 1000's of things on the screen at once, you might want to look into using DirectX with a wrapper like SlimDx or SharpDx.

Comment: That library looks really nice. I persume moving / rotating / resizing shapes would be something I need to implement like in Java2D?

Comment: There's a branch that has resize and rotate methods.  I've never used them, but worth a look.

Comment: After some testing I can say: It's crazy fast compared to pure WPF and it's really simple. I found rotation and resizing for the whole picture, but it is not a big problem to implement it figure-wise. Thanks a lot for the hint to this library, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So you basically need two lines, one that looks like before and one that looks like what it will be like when the user "commits" his changes? You could have a container class that holds two identical shape types and move the second one when the user is in edit mode. When the user exits edit mode, you can either keep the first (user cancelled) or make the second the new, one and only first shape.

Comment: I need only one line which start point will be set on mouse down and the end point will move with the cursor till I release the button. So I need a good way to update the property that helds the end point of the Line in the GUI from my model class.